# ASCII number for exponent -2 and -3

Tags: math, exponentiation

I am trying to find an ascii formation to have a unit in a graph in exponent -2 and -3. For example mm^(-2). I found the relevant ascii formation for exponent 2 and 3 but i cannot find how to include the - sympol in the exponent.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you're trying to do and what you need :/

Comment: For example if you need to have the unit mm2 you write: mm (alt+253) and you get mm^2. I need mm^-2.

Comment: I need the minus sign to be in the exponent.

Comment: The [ASCII character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) does not contain any superscript characters. You must mean some other character set. (People often do when they say ASCII.)

Comment: ASCII has no exponent characters. You may have seen an other encoding (ASCII go just until 127, so your 253 is outside std ASCII). But you should not use such characters for exponents. This is a format issue, which should be handled by markdown formatting (LaTeX, HTML, ...)

Comment: I'm guessing OP meant Unicode, which does have "⁻" and "²" which you could combine into "mm⁻²".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the character set you are using. If Unicode then there is ['SUPERSCRIPT MINUS' (U+207B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/207b/index.htm) but not superscript minus two. So, as two characters, mm⁻².

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts